# Google photo reference image download and upload to S3

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am working on download google photo reference image and directly upload to S3 after verifying that image exists on url in PHP. Now currently I am unable to download image from google photo reference image

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=XXXXXXXXX
```

When hit this url in web browser that browser redirect me to the another URL. Now I simply verify this url that image exists on this url or not if image exists oh this url and url is valid then simply upload this image to S3 bucket I am using Lumen microservice for this task.

If there is any third party library that provide this functionality and provide help to comlete this task. So kindly suggest.